# ocaml sprintf clarification

Tags: ocaml, printf

I do not understand why this is the case:

```
Printf.sprintf "%08s" "s" = Printf.sprintf "%8s" "s"
- : bool = true
```

In other words, I would expect:

```
Printf.sprintf "%08s" "s"
- : string = "0000000s"
```

and not the actual result:

```
- : string = "       s"
```

could someone please clarify why this is so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation of `printf`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html), you can see that the `0` flag does not apply to `%s`.

> 0: **for numerical conversions**, pad with zeroes instead of spaces.

(Emphasis is mine.)

Notice that, in C, it leads to an undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the precise, quick answer :) I'll mark it as answered.  I seem to have somehow managed to gloss over that important detail in the documentation. Apologies!

Answer (score 2):

When I try your format specifier in C, I get the following warning:

```
warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier
```

Assuming my compiler isn't crazy (Mac OS X 10.8.2), this would suggest that OCaml's conversion is fine.